# Shortening the physical length of a text input field Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I was wondering how to shorten the length of a text input field in html. My code looks like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :quote_number, :id => 'quote_number', :autocomplete => 'off' %>
```

I've tried switching it to something like this but this hasn't worked:

```
<td><input type="quote_number" id="quote_number" size="1" />
```

Editing the first line of code is preferred but if that's not possible I feel like there should be a way for the second line to work. Thanks

**Update:** I can change the length of the **first name** field by using this code:

```
<input type="firstname" id="cFirstName" size="1" />
```

but I still can't change the length of the **Quote#** field by using this code:

```
<input type="quote_number" id="quote_number" maxlength="1" size="1" />
```

My table that the user sees looks like this now:

[image]

The number in the **Quote#** field is generated as soon as the page loads. Could this be the issue and is there a way around it so I shorten the length?

Comment: Why don't you use a framework like Bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: `<%= f.text_field :quote_number, maxlength: 10 %>` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around all the code and head to the CSS. I just changed the width in the quote_number field like this:

```
#quote_number  {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Did you want to change physical length of the field or limit number of chars in input field?

Comment: I wanted to change the physical length, sorry for any confusion